# Change text on Fragment on button click

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I want to make a quiz app. So i want to change the question statement in `fragment` . How can i do that [image]

Comment: please add your code where you are stuck and explain your questions a bit more.

Comment: Post complete question  with fragment and activity code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to create QuestionType list with `question, option1, option2, option3, option3,` correct option.
and on `onclick` button get question from list and change values for your `radio group`.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an `ArrayList consisting Questions, answer and options`.

On clicking Next Question, you just need to change the index of the arraylist.

When its the last question just change the text of button to `Submit`

Answer (score 0):

Store your question in ArrayList or some permanent storage like DB and then traverse list until last item is reached.Fetch value and set to textView by using setText() method.

Answer (score 0):

Activity can call fragment method by acquiring a reference to the Fragment.

Call fragment like this-

```
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, "myfragmentTag");
```

and by the help of fragment object you can call fragment method

```
myFragment.refreshQuestion();
```

**You can also use the Interface to achieve this**